# Disable form fields and enable them after clicking on edit button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form fields in which I am displaying data.

The values should be disabled and edit button should appear, after clicking on Edit button, the values should be enabled and user can edit the data and only save button should appear

How to achieve these two requirements in a single form in Asp.Net MVC4?

Comment: This functionality can only be achieved with the help of Jquery..

Answer (score 0):

Use templates.

An ITEM TEMPLATE and then an EDIT TEMPLATE.

When the user presses the EDIT button, set the action to change to mode of the form to EDIT.

Comment: I think you are talking about WebForms? He is using MVC.